# hibernate avoid the id

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

It's the first time I'm using hibernate, so forgive me if I'm going to ask for easy advice.
 I'm currently mapping a class using the xml (no annotations), I don't have the id on my table, but someone told me that I'm compeled to use an ID using hibernate, so, I created the SMS_MONITORING_ID field into the table and I'm mapping it as following:

```
 <class name="smsbox.dal.model.SmsMonitoring" table="MST_SMS_MONITORING">
    <comment></comment>

    <id name="smsMonitoringId" type="long">
        <column name="SMS_MONITORING_ID" />
        <generator class="native" >
            <param name="sequence">ID_SMS_MONITORING</param>
        </generator>

    </id>
```

I already made a sequence on my oracle database (ID_SMS_MONITORING), and I don't want that hibernate handle the id at all, I even would like to avoid any reference to the id in my java code (when I save the object).
How could I accomplish my will to let hibernate ignoring the whole process in assigning the id ?

P.S I'm mapping the id (long) into an Oracle "Number" type, what is the rule to avoid possible problem (long dosen't fit into number or vice-versa) can anybody provide me some link that explaing well the mapping types Hibernate and Oracle DB (I didn't find anything interesting on my own).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, every mapped entity should have ID mapped as every relational database demands it.

The ID is assigned to the object only when you persist your object, so you need to use your sequence in Hibernate. More than this, you need to create equals and hashcode functions with more parameters than ID, because if you have two objects and their IDs are null and your equals and hashcode functions are using ID only, both objects are equal in Hibernate and might be the root cause for a lot of problems in your code.

Comment: You actually don't need an ID, but some sort of key, possibly a compound key. If you want to do updates it would of course have to be unique. But there is no reason for an ID to be a single column, or to be numeric.

Comment: I disagree with you, according to hibernate there should be primary key on each table and primary key is always unique, but you are right that I can create primary key of any type even composite type.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the Hibernate documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

you'll see that the  tag is optional. Leaving it undefined is equivalente to set it as "assigned" (in other words, your application will handle the id assignment).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to declare the id generator as following

```
 <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">YourSquenceName</param>
      </generator>
```

when you save your object with hibernate, you dont have to get/set Id, and just leave the id field as null, Hibernate will get an valid id from your sequence.